# Auto-Size Columns In DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

This is my HTML for my grid, how can I set the columns to auto-fit so that one column is not really huge when it is not needed?  I know I can manually set the size, but I would rather it auto-size as some store names are longer than others and some manager names are longer than others so a pre-determined size isn't a good option.

```
      <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dtgMain" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
CssClass="DataGrids" GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="true" OnItemCommand="dtgMain_OnItemCommand">
  <ItemStyle CssClass="row" />
  <FooterStyle CssClass="DataGridFooters" />
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="DataGridHeaders" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="storename" HeaderText="storename"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="hours" HeaderText="hours"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Date" HeaderText="Today's Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="manager" HeaderText="Store Manager"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Store Owner"></asp:BoundColumn>
  </Columns>
  </asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought they auto-size by default..

Try: `ItemStyle-Width="Auto"`